# @GET Accept JSON input in spring Restful Webservice?

Tags: json, spring, web-services, rest

I have designed a controller that should display data of the employee I specify in a JSON file.

When I execute a POST request with JSON data it works, however when I try to execute a GET request with the same parameter it does not work. Can you explain why ?

GET can accpet json DATA?

```
// It works
@RequestMapping(value = EmpRestURIConstants.CREATE_EMP, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Employee createEmployee(@RequestBody Employee emp) {
    logger.info("Start createEmployee.");
    string Id = emp.getId();
    System.out.prinltn(Id);// it showing value      
    return emp;     
}

// It doesn't work
@RequestMapping(value = EmpRestURIConstants.CREATE_EMP, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Employee createEmployee(@RequestBody Employee emp) {       
     logger.info("Start createEmployee.");
     string Id = emp.getId();
     System.out.prinltn(Id); // it showing null
     return emp;
}

// passing parameter.
{
    "Id" :"SOMEID"  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

GET request have not message body. You can only pass parameter with the URL.

example : 
     www.exemple.com/toto?**parameter1=myparameter1**

You can also use the RESTful style url.

More information here :
https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

Answer (score 0):

Since `GET` requests have their data not in the Request body, you need to remove the `@RequestBody` annotation

```
// should do the job
@RequestMapping(value = EmpRestURIConstants.CREATE_EMP, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Employee createEmployee(Employee emp) {       
    logger.info("Start createEmployee.");
    string Id = emp.getId();
    System.out.prinltn(Id);
    return emp;
}

// if you have no object, with a setter for id, you can also map the requestParameter of the URL directly
@RequestMapping(value = EmpRestURIConstants.CREATE_EMP, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Employee createEmployee(@RequestParam(value = "id") empId) {       
    logger.info("Start createEmployee.");
    System.out.prinltn(empId);
    return emp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If a method parameter is annotated with @RequestBody, Spring will bind the incoming HTTP request body(for the URL mentioned in @RequestMapping for that method) to that parameter. While doing that, Spring will [behind the scenes] use HTTP Message converters to convert the HTTP request body into domain object [deserialize request body to domain object], based on Accept header present in request.

The Accept header is used by HTTP clients [browsers] to tell the server what content types they’ll accept.
The server sends back the response, which will include a Content-Type header telling the client what the content type of the returned content actually is. In case of POST or PUT request, browsers do send data in request, so they actually send content-type as well.

Courtesy: 
http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-mvc-requestbody-responsebody-example/